# variable/resource concatenation in toast not working

Tags: android, concatenation, toast

This works:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), attemptsRemainingCount.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This works:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.attemptsRemaining, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This however, does not work:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), attemptsRemainingCount.toString() + R.string.attemptsRemaining, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

All it gives me is a long number. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong with the concatenation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're concatenating java variable with a Resource Identifier.

Try using following:

> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), attemptsRemainingCount.toString() + getResources().getString(R.string.attemptsRemaining), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Thanks for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is using a `CharSequence` which in turn calls the `CharSequence` version of `makeText`:

[`makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int))

And your second example is using the `resId` or linked resource id version:

[`makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int))

That explains why the two examples work.

What you want is a combination of both. This means you need to convert the linked resource id to a `String`, then concatenate it and use the `CharSequence` method. For example, like so:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    attemptsRemainingCount.toString() + 
    getResources().getString(R.string.attemptsRemaining), 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines may look the same, but they will use different overloaded versions of `Toast.makeText`. The first uses [the `CharSequence` version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) (because it is given a string) while the second uses [the int version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) (because it is given a integer resource id.

Concatenating the string with a resource id (a number) still results in a string, but with the resource id converted to string.

Instead you should make the string resource into a format string (`You have %1$d attempts left`) and use:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.attemptsRemaining,  attemptsRemainingCount);
```

To get the formatted string. See the section `Formatting strings` in [the string resources documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) for full details.

The advantage of format strings in string resources over simply concatenating the number with a fixed string is that the former can easily be translated into other languages where the number may not be at the same place.